# Post method inside a post method

Tags: django, post

I have the following code:

```
<form class="square" action="{% url 'interface:modify_device_perform' %}" method="post">

    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>ID device</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="device_id" value="{{ device.id }}" readonly />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Device name</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="device_human" value="{{ device.human_id }}" placeholder="Example: Box 2" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Associated patient</label>
        {% if device.user_set.get.id != '' %}
            <input class="form-control" value= "{{ device.user_set.get.id }}" readonly>  </input>
        {% else %}
            <input class="form-control"  value= "No patient" readonly>  </input>
        {% endif %}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Device position</label>
        <select name="position_id" class="form-control">
            {% for position in position_list %}
                {% if position == device.position %}
                    <option selected="selected">{{ position.id }}</option>
                {% else %}
                    <option>{{ position.id }}</option>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            {% if device.position == None %}
                <option selected="selected"> No position </option>
            {% else %}
                <option> No position </option>
            {% endif %}
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group square_button">
        <button class="btn btn-warning btn-md form-control" type="submit"> Modify Device </button>
    </div>

</form>
```

This represents the following:

[image]

The problem is that I want to add a button on the right of `No patient` that makes a post request, making possible to remove a patient associated in case it has one.

How I can add that post request inside a post request?

Comment: Can you describe more? What exactly you want after click `No patient` button?

Comment: This is a Django web server. I just need to make a post request with the Associated patient to one view method.

Comment: I mean.. you want to 2 button in form, right? If you click `modify device` and form is submit, send POST request. And if you click other button - then it should goes with other POST (or get) request. So just make other view

Comment: Yes, I want the modify button that send post reqeust with all information, and another button that removes the patient of that device.

Comment: Then you can use ajax, check answer from @Parth below. With ajax, you can send POST request without reloading page - so you can remove patient of that device without comming off from the page.

Comment: And what about if I want to make a post reloading the page?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171060/discussion-between-seuling-and-lechucico).

Answer (score 1):

You can Do that With ajax, for that you need to add some code in your javascript/jquery.

You can put button to the right side of the "No patient" and add a click event for that in javascript. make ajax request in with post url and get your response in the success function of ajax. 
you can refer ajax and its methods on https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_ajax.asp

Hope it will help you.